# Support all orientations without autorotate in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

The view right after the launch screen is required to be presented in the device's orientation but should not autorotate to other orientations once it is presented. I used this code :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    [super shouldAutorotate];

    return YES;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

This works well for iPad but in iPhone, setting NO for shouldAutorotate results in Portrait only. Is this normal behaviour? If so how can all orientations be supported without autorotation in iPhone, for a particular view controller only?

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect what orientation the device is in when you start up:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Convert that to an interface orientation:

```
switch (orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    default:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Now store it somewhere for global access and return that:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return globalOrientation;
}
```